# Python: List to integers

Tags: python, list, integer

I have read a file in and converted each line into a list. A sample of the list looks like:

['15', '2', '0'], ['63', '3', '445', '456' '0'], ['23', '4', '0']

i want to retrieve the first number from each list and convert it to and integer so when i carry out the type function i.e.

```
type(x) 
<type 'int'> is returned
```

Also when i print x the integers are printed individually rather than joined. i.e. if i took the first 3 numbers from the list above the numbers are not printed as:

> 156323

Comment: Your question is kind of vague as to how you want the output to be. Please specify.

Comment: It would be more useful if you told us how you want the numbers printed, instead of what you *don't* want (as I'm assuming there is an infinite number of these).

Answer (score 12):

To cast your ints:

```
my_ints = [int(l[0]) for l in your_list]
```

To print them out:

```
print "".join(map(str, my_ints))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list with the first number of each list, `[int(L[0]) for L in lines]` (assuming the list of lists is called `lines`); if you want the first *two* numbers of each list (it's hard to tell from your question), `[int(s) for L in lines for s in L[:2]]`; and so forth.

If you don't want a list of such numbers, but just to do one iteration on them, you can use a generator expression, i.e.:

```
for number in (int(s) for L in lines for s in L[:2]):
  ...do something with number...
```

or an equivalent nested-loop approach such as:

```
for L in lines:
  for s in L[:2]:
    number = int(s)
    ...do something with number...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Converts all items in all lists to integers.
ls = [map(int, x) for x in the_first_list]
```

Or if you just want the first two items:

```
ls = [map(int, x[:2]) for x in the_first_list]
```

In python 3.x you'd have to also wrap the map in a list constructor, like this

```
ls = [list(map(int, x[:2])) ...
```

Comment: +1, though not sure if the inner list comprehension is what the OP is looking for. perhaps [map(int, x) for x in the_first_list] ?

Comment: This converts all items to integers and keeps the list intact, he just wants the first number of each list.

Comment: I changed it slightly to convert it to a list.

Comment: instead of saying the_first_list shouldn't this read lists[0]

Comment: not really. that would, through coincidence, convert only the first list, and the output would be this: [[1, 5], [2], [0]]

Comment: Wrapping the `map(int, x[:2])` in a `list()` call is redundant in 2.x, since `map()` returns a list.  Is this intended to be a 3.x example?

Comment: Yes, I used it in 3.x. Wasn't sure how map works in 2.x, but thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, it is  `[int x[0] for x in list_of_lists]`

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [['15', '2', '0'], ['63', '3', '445', '456' '0'], ['23', '4', '0']]
first_values_as_ints = [int(line[0]) for line in lines]
for x in first_values_as_ints:
    print x,
```