# Python: List of lists of integers to absolute value to single number

Tags: python, list, mapping, integer, absolute

If i had a list of list of integers say:

> [['12' '-4' '66' '0'], ['23' '4' '-5'
>   '0'], ['23' '77' '89' '-1' '0']]

I wanted to convert the numbers to their absolute values and then to a single number, so the output would be:

> 1246602345023778910

Comment: the numbers in your example are strings actually, is this intended?

Comment: Is this anything like your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914883, or the one you asked just before that as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909619 ?  If the missing part was simply the use of abs() to get the absolute value, I think you need to work through the Python tutorial and review the builtin functions.

Comment: after reading your other questions (thanks to peter) I have the impression that a more elegant file parsing algorithm might solve your problem too. if you are only interested in digits, why not parse only the input's digits?

Comment: I think this is the fourth time you've asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

What you're showing is (maybe) a list of lists of strings, and the syntax is extremely peculiar -- the sublists are shown with the normal, usual commas, but inside each there are just literal strings with spaces between them.  If you actually type that into Python, you'll get a list where each sublist contains a single string -- Python, like C, concatenates at compile time string literals that are simply juxtaposed with whitespace in the middle.

Assuming you did mean to have sublists of several strings each, WITH proper commas, and that your mentions of "lists of numbers" (which is not what you have -- you have lists of strings!-) are just small accidents, something like:

```
''.join(c for L in thelist for c in L).replace('-', '')
```

is probably best -- just operate at the string level (so, replace dashes with nothing, rather than using `abs`), since you do need strings for concatenation/joining purposes anyway.

If you're keen to do it the most complicated way you can,

```
''.join(str(abs(int(c))) for L in thelist for c in L)
```

will also work (and more literally match what you're asking), but the first idea's better.

Answer (score 1):

What you gave above is a list of lists of strings.

I suggest a two-pass approach:

1. Get integers from strings and take their absolutes:

   [ abs(int(s)) for s in list ]
2. Combine these numbers into a string and turn it into an integer

   ''.join([ ''.join(x) for x in listoflists ])

When you combine these two approaches you get:

```
>>> listoflists = [['12','-4','66','0'],['23','4','-5','0'],['23','77','89','-1','0']]
>>> int(''.join([ ''.join([ str(abs(int(s))) for s in list ]) for list in listoflists ]))
1246602345023778910L
```

It's not nice and readable though, so you may want to keep it divided to make more sense to someone who might have the take the pain of understanding it.

Note: If you indeed had a list of integers though, as you stated, then it's much easier:

```
>>> listofints = [12,-4,66,0,23,4,-5,0,23,77,89,-1,0]
>>> int(''.join( [ str(abs(x)) for x in listofints ]))
1246602345023778910L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.chain here to get rid of the nesting, concatenate the number-strings, remove the '-' signs and then turn them into a number.

```
import itertools
mylist = [['12' '-4' '66' '0'], ['23' '4' '-5' '0'], ['23' '77' '89' '-1' '0']]
num = int( ''.join(itertools.chain(*mylist)).replace('-','') )
```

Edit: I previously missed the abs requirement.
Second edit: Used replace which is probably more efficient than str(abs(int(n))) and also less clumsy (courtesy: Alex's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Python, so please forgive me if there is a more efficient way :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = ''
lists = [['12' '-4' '66' '0'], ['23' '4' '-5' '0'], ['23' '77' '89' '-1' '0']]

for list in lists:
  str += list[0].replace('-', '')

print int(str)
```

Comment: Why are you replacing in list[0] alone?

Comment: ['12' '-4' '66' '0'] isn't a list within a list.  Its a single list with concatenated strings.  Therefore, you only need to replace the hyphen in the first member of the list.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answers, your inner lists are not as 'listy' as they appear.  Since commas are missing, Python will (I think) concatenate them all into one string thus giving you a list of one item.  This will be the same as this:

```
[['12-4660'], ['234-50'], ['237789-10']]
```

In any case, you *could* just strip out eveything that's not a digit to get your result (this would work with or without the commas):

```
''.join(x for x in str(mylist) if x.isdigit())
```